# How to to resize grid images based on screen size?

Tags: android, layout

I have a grid layout with image and text view..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="55dp"
         android:id="@+id/testheader"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#3a08ff"

        android:textSize="10dip" />





    </RelativeLayout>
```

There seems no problem when i view it in small screen size device. But when i view the same in larger device the image view looks so smaller. How can i overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ScaleType property of imageview keep it as

```
Scaletype="fitXY"
```

hope so it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 int h,w;

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int density = metrics.densityDpi;

            int width = 0, height = 0;
            metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
             getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


             height = metrics.heightPixels;     
             width = metrics.widthPixels;


if(width >480 && width <780)
             {
                 setContentView(R.layout.home_module);

                 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 

                    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
                   if(density <200)
                   {
                       h=200;
                       w=200;

                       CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList, prgmImages,h,w); 
                       gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       h=200;
                       w=200;
                       CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList, prgmImages,h,w); 

                       gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
                   }
            }
             else if(width<=480)
             {
                 setContentView(R.layout.home_module);    
                 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 

                    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
                       h=150;
                       w=150;
                       CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList, prgmImages,h,w); 

                         gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 

             }

             else if(width >= 780)
             {
                 setContentView(R.layout.home_module);               
                 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 

                    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
                   if(density <200)
                   {
                       h=200;
                       w=200;
                       CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList, prgmImages,h,w); 
                       gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       h=200;
                       w=200;
                       CustomAdapter mAdapter;
                       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList, prgmImages,h,w); 
                       gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
                   }
             }
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

create a different layout folder like
res/layout-large/layout.xml
you can specify the size of android:columnWidth="XYZdp" something larger
Please see 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html